# Can I use a pointer to traverse an array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, vector

there.
I am now studying C++ Primer. When I writing a piece of program something about pointer confused me.
The function of the program below is reading strings into a vector and copying the vector into an array of character pointers. For each element in the vector, allocate a new character array and copy the data from the vector element into that character array. Then print the contents of array of strings.

Here is my piece of code:

```
vector<string> str_vector;
string str_temp;
while(getline(cin,str_temp)){
    str_vector.push_back(str_temp);
}

typedef const char *cptr;
cptr *cptr_array = new cptr[str_vector.size()];

cptr *p = cptr_array;

for(vector<string>::iterator iter = str_vector.begin(); 
    iter != str_vector.end(); iter++,p++){
    *p = (*iter).c_str();
}

cout<<"Output Char Array Element"<<endl;
cptr *q = cptr_array;
while(*q){
    cout<<*q<<endl;
    q++;
}

delete [] cptr_array;
```

When I run the program it will crash at after output the array of strings. 
I could use the following code to do the same thing without any crash.

```
cptr *q = cptr_array;
for(int i = 0; i < str_vector.size(); i++,q++){
    cout<<*q<<endl;
}
```

I just want to know why the output code above could not work correctly. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*q = cptr_array;
while(*q){
```

Not only will the loop dereference an out-of-bounds `q` after traversing the array, you can't test with `while(q)` either because there's no nullptr sentinel at the end of the array.  The simplest thing to do is allocate one more element in `cptr` than you need to hold pointers to all the string values and then set the pointer value of that last element to `nullptr` (`0`).

Comment: Thanks David, your answer is in detail and helpful. I have applied your suggestion in my code, works pretty good!

Answer (score 2):

```
while(*q){
```

You are using `*q` as the condition. After the array is iterated over, `q` points to places after the end of the array, accessing `*q` is illegal.